# How to determine which drive in a firmware RAID is failing

Tags: hard-drive, raid, smart, hard-drive-failure

I have two drives in an Intel ICH10 RAID 1. They are not enterprise-level drives; just regular WD Caviar Black drives.

Recently, reading/writing to the mirrored volume has become extremely slow and the HDD light is on constantly. I suspect that this may be due to one of the disks becoming close to failure and attempting [sector remapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Error_rates_and_handling). (See also [What is the fastest way to force hdd to reallocate bad sectors and discard the data?](https://superuser.com/q/721216/32370)). If this was an enterprise drive, it would fail quickly and cleanly, but this behavior is typical of consumer drives. Hence, it's not immediately clear which drive is bad.

Neither of the drives shows problematic SMART data (this is from the [Intel SSD Toolbox](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=18455) which seems to be one of the few options for reading SMART data off an Intel firmware RAID):

### First drive

[image]

### Second drive

[image]

Unfortunately, the WD [Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://support.wd.com/product/download.asp?groupid=810&sid=3&lang=en) tool which is able to run SMART tests is completely confused by the Intel ICH10 RAID:

[image]

How can I tell which drive is the problematic one and swap it out?

Comment: Did you run a short SMART test on each drive to make sure the SMART data is not misleading? If the SMART test fails (it only takes about 5 minutes if it works properly), you have your culprit.

Comment: I checked out the WD [Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://support.wd.com/product/download.asp?groupid=810&sid=3&lang=en). Unfortunately it completely sucks at life.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, the **first drive** is defective. `Read Error Rate` and `Re-allocated Sector Count` are non-zero. Re-allocating sectors is exactly what happens when the drive can not read a sector. It will then re-allocate this sector on the next write operation.

You can do several things to confirm this diagnosis:

**Simple but uncertain:** use a tool like [HDD Scan](http://hddscan.com/) to scan your disk, i.e., read every sector from your disk. You can also do this operation on your RAID 1 array. But than it is up to the RAID-firmware to decide if it will read the data from disk 1 oder disk 2. Therefore this method will not check every sector on both disks. But if disk 1 is about to fail, it is quite probable (but not guaranteed), that its SMART values will worsen.

Keep an eye on `Re-allocated Sector Count`, `Reallocation Event Count` and `Current Pending Sector Count`. If these values go up, your drive is likely to fail soon.

**Complicated but gives more certainty:**

1. Mount your drives in a different pc/usb-enclosure/different SATA-port.
2. Boot from a Live CD (e.g. Ubuntu or Knoppix).
3. Perform a **read only** test of your drives. You can do this by SMART commands and/or by using tools like `dd` or `badblocks`

   - do NOT attempt to mount the filesystem
   - do NOT write *anything* to the drive
   - when you do read-only operations, you can re-assemble the RAID without it beeing marked as faulty/inconsistent.
4. Keep an eye on the same values as mentioned above. Now you should also be able to read the SMART values properly. SMART usually also has a log about previous errors that happened. Drive 1 hat at least two of them. The timestamp is usually expressed as power-on-hours. So you will have to calculate back from the current power-on-hours and see if this correlates with the time you experienced the problems.

Comment: Does one read error or reallocated sector really mean the drive is about to fail?

Comment: One `Re-allocated Sector Count` does not mean something bad per se. The more interesting value is `Current Pending Sector Count`. The reason is: If a drive can not read a sector it increases `Current Pending Sector Count` and "remembers" that the sector is broken. Depending on the firmware it will try to read it again if the OS wants to read the sector again. The Sector is only re-allocated if you WRITE something to it. After the write `Re-allocated Sector Count` is increased.